# How to make this get all words in the file

Tags: python, windows

So I have been trying to make a programming language very simply and I encountered something I can't do. I'm trying to see if every word in a file has this text in it but I don't know how to get every word. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
with open("hello.dita","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.split().pop(0)) == "print":
            if line.split().pop(1) == "-s":
                print(line.split().pop(2))
```

hello.dita contains:

```
print -s hello print -s this works?
```

and its outputs:

```
hello
```

Comment: "every word in a file has this text" - which text?

Comment: Your code doesn't even run. There are too many closing )). Maybe you fix the code before asking the question. We want a [mre]

Comment: @ThomasWeller if it has "print", and then next to it has "-s", and then print what they put next, the hello.dita file contains this: print -s hello

Comment: Please correct the errors mentioned by Thomas Weller, and add the output you are seeing from the working code, as requested by j1-lee. You may need to append a partial example of the source file being read, too, so we can see what it is supposed to be reading.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that the intended output is `hello` followed by `this works?` on the next line?

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want to recognise a line with the format `print -s text` and print the text. Your error here is that pop index by default is -1, so this code will work:

```py
with open("hello.dita", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.split().pop(0) == "print":
            if line.split().pop(1) == "-s":
                print(line.split().pop(2))
```

But you can do some upgrades for improve the performance, like store the splitted string in a variable to avoid repitting the same split, and use the [] instead of pop to avoid list modification:

```py
with open("hello.dita", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        arguments = line.split()
        if arguments[0] == "print":
            if arguments[1] == "-s":
                print(arguments[2])
```

Another possible error, is that your code will fail for a line like `print` or `print -s`, so you should check the list length:

```py
with open("hello.dita", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        arguments = line.split()
        if len(arguments) >= 1 and arguments[0] == "print":
            if len(arguments) >= 3 and arguments[1] == "-s":
                print(arguments[2])
```

And at least, if you want that the text can contain white spaces, you can do:

```py
with open("hello.dita", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        arguments = line.split()
        if len(arguments) >= 1 and arguments[0] == "print":
            if len(arguments) >= 3 and arguments[1] == "-s":
                print(' '.join(arguments[2:]))
```